# Do I need to know web application development to make mobile apps?

Tags: android, iphone, web-applications, mobile-application

So I am looking to learn both web application development and mobile app development, and I was wondering is there is an overlap between the two. More specifically, is the knowledge of developing web apps essential or even helpful when building mobile apps?
I was under the impression that one had to know basic web app development first (at least server side programming) before being able to develop mobile apps that use the internet (since I assumed a mobile app is just a different client side that would ultimately have to talk to a web application on a server somewhere). However, Googling this brings up discussions about mobile web apps vs. native mobile apps, and this has me confused (for example is Shazaam a native or a web app?).
Please help me understand.

Comment: yeah, this is not how it works @niks. you give a good answer, and then you get voted. you don't get to ask people to vote/accept your answer. -1

Answer (score 2):

A native app is an app that execute on your mobile.
A web app is an app that open a webPage inside your mobile app and act like a classic web browser.

You don't have to know web dev to do mobile dev, but it can help, programming is the same for every platform, you just have to know new language every time you change, but principles are the same.

Comment: But many mobile apps do need to go to a server to do it's work right? In that case, does it do so using the http GET/POST requests, or is it doing something else?

Comment: for interaction with a web server you use apple's classes for http connection, it does it using http GET.

Answer (score 1):

Knowledge of developing web application isn't necessary for developing mobile application. But, It will help you a lot. You can also build mobile app with HTML5,CSS & JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

You can develop mobile apps which do not need any web components at all.

I see at least two big issues which make web development extremely useful for mobile apps

- You could develop non native mobile app based on web technology. Using jQuery mobile or GWT (or other framework) will support platform independence for you apps. The back-draw is this application could not use all features of the mobile device (e.g. camera), and they will in general have less performance and battery/power efficiency.
- I find it very natural to use cloud techniques in combination with mobile. You could use the web to save and share data. And this allows you to build application driven by mobile AND desktop (desktop is much more efficient when it comes to data input)

I would recommend to look at web technology, too.

Answer (score 1):

Sooner or later, your mobile application would need to talk to a a server to do something useful - the phone is the thin-client (relatively speaking). So yes, usually, you would use a server side language (like PHP or RoR) to build some kind of API for your mobile application to talk to and be useful.

For example, since you bought up Shazaam (which is a native application): Shazaam would record a few seconds of music using and then uploads to a web service that does all the heavy lifting of sampling the recorded music and looking it up on a (what I would imagine) giant DB of music for the 'signature' of that music and sending the identified song back to the phone so it can be presented to the user. Somewhere along the way, there is server side code that does this.

I've worked at companies when mobile app development as just starting to take off (2008-09) where there were guys who only coded Java for Android/Blackberry or Objective-C for iOS and didn't know jack about what happens in the backend. For that, they talked the server-side guys who wrote JSP or python to build the APIs their native code would talk to.

There are servics [Parse](https://parse.com/) that would allow you do build a "backend" for your mobile application without needing worry about getting your own server or writing server side code. Useful for certain classes of applications.

I hope that all makes sense. There is definitely an overlap between web development (as in server side) and mobile development (native code on the mobile). Learn both, specialize in one if you have to.

Comment: Not always. There are many, many apps that work purely offline.

Answer (score 1):

You can start learning Mobile App Development without any prior knowledge of Web/Enterprise Application Development.

But, it would definitely make your job easier if you do have that knowledge. You need to know the basics of `RESTServices` (cause this is mainly how you would interact with a Server from the Mobile App), know how `HTTP POST, GET, DELETE`,etc work. Also experience with `MySQL` or `SQL` whill help your for using `SQLite`(which is basically your DB on mobile apps). Also if you have some knoledge about `ORMs` such as `Hibernate`, may also help you in your mobile app, if you have a large model, and a large data structure that you cache on your device, and it would allow you to use `ORMLite`(on Android for example).

Definitely all this things will help you a lot, and any other experience regarding programming standards/ design patterns/ Java/ Objective-C will make your work easier, and your developed products more reliable/stable.

Good luck.

Comment: @downvoter, care to comment what was wrong?

Comment: I read your answer and am also puzzled why you got down-voted - nothing you said appears to be wrong or misleading.

Comment: yeah,revenge. somebody got mad cause I downvoted his question because he had written 'Please vote and accept my answer'.

Answer (score 1):

A web app is a website (sometimes but not always aimed at a mobile device) using a different set to technologies/languages (php/perl/.net/xhtml/ccs etc) than native app development (obj c, c++, java).

Yes it's useful to have some knowledge of both, but if I was you I would concentrate on one path (one thing at once) either server/back-end/web-app/web-site building or mobile development. I worked over 10 years in a web software development environment before deciding to move to mobile app development. Now I do no web coding, I use existing web-services or work with someone else who does the web-services side of things.

It also depends what types of apps you want to build. If you want to write games for mobile devices then you don't need to learn any web stuff. Use Apple' Game Center for the leader boards etc.

Even if you want to write mobile apps that communicate with web services, I suggest writing a few apps that consume existing web-services first, so you can concentrate on building something that works without trying to learn more than one programming language at once. There are plenty of web-sites out there with web-services you can use to create your own apps.

There are options out there for writing apps using web technologies (phoneGap, titanium etc.) but I would avoid them personally.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. You mention using existing web services to write mobile apps while learning - do you have any examples of these?

Comment: try http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory

Answer (score 0):

Well, basic knowledge on web applications is very useful. After all, as you said, a mobile app is just another type of client. Knowing the principles of web communications is essential. The server side of an application is quite the same. As far as the client side is concerned, transferring your code from java to android is quite easy...!

Comment: Cool - but will the request/repsonse between mobile app and web server remain the same (ie. GET/POST, etc?)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is upto how you want to build you mobile app. If your app can do something locally, then there is no need to know web programming. But if your app wants to communicate with server, or wants to use web stuff (such as rendering the HTML5 and javascript), then you'd better know web programming. Both native and web app can do the thing, but different pros and cons. There are also platforms that helps you develop the mobile app using html and js then turn it to native code such as titanium.

IMHO, the processing of mobile app should be done on server if possible. In that way, the app can do more and is more efficient. Therefore, knowing web app development will be a big plus.

Comment: So when a mobile app talks to a server, is it doing so using the POST/GET requests we see in web programming?

Comment: Yes, and I think it's the best way to do. It is very common to use HTTP request in your app, especially if you wanted to use external service such as posting the tweet or sharing on facebook.

How much do you need to know about web dev so that you can write a mobile app? I think it's up to the case. If the stake holder provides you the API, knowing only how to make a web request seems to be enough. But if you wanted to move all business logic to server, then you need to know it seriously.